# How would I recreate the following CSS code in Web Animation API

Tags: css, web-animations-api

Looking at this site: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

I found this [image: https://i2.wp.com/css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/animate-stroke-full.gif]

I am now at a loss how to try to change the same property (stroke-dashoffset) using the web animation api WAAPI, anyone have any clue or where I should be searching for this information?

I cannot find out what keywords to use in my [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats), or what is valid things to write in there even

Answer (score 1):

I missed the small but important print in the keyframe specification, change the property name from stroke-dashoffset to strokeDashoffset and it will work the same